# In R, find duplicates based on at least X of Y columns

Tags: r

I am trying to identify *suspect* duplicate rows in a dataset based on duplicated names and a number of matching duplicate columns in the dataframe.

Another way of saying this would be, for each duplicate naming pair (i.e. - where first and last names combined for each row are identical across rows), are at least X other (non-name) columns duplicated as well, for each naming pair.

This is difficult to describe so some dummy data might help.

Sample starting dummy data (not the actual data or people):

```
df <- data.frame(
FirstName = c("Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel"),
LastName = c("White",   "White",    "Adams",    "Adams",    "Andrews",  "Andrews",  "Thomas",   "Thomas", "Brown", "Brown"),
City = c("Phoenix", "MESA", "Denver",   "Albany",   "Washington",   "Washington",   "Tampa", "Taos",    "Orlando", NA),
State = c("AZ", "AZ",   "CO",   "NY",   "DC",   "VA",   "FL",   "NM",   "FL", NA),
Group1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "XWZ", "XWZ", "LMN", "LMN", "XWZ", "MMM", NA, NA),
Group2 = c("D001", "D001", "A444", "A444", "M555", "M555", "E333", "F222", "Q777", "Q777"),
Group3 = c("FORT", "FORT", "SETS", "SETS", "SETS", "SETS", "FORT", "FORT", "SETS", "SETS")
)
```

Which would look like this:

[image: Dummy data]

For each row with the same name (First and Last combined), if at least 3 of the remaining columns are duplicated as well then treat it as a likely duplicate (the number could change so next time it might be 2 columns, 4 columns, etc.).

For example, the first two rows are both "Daniel White" (FirstName and LastName paired) and even though the *Cities* column data are different ("Phoenix" vs. "Mesa") the *State*, *Group1*, *Group2*, and *Group3* columns are all the same.  Since 4 out of 5 columns beyond the name columns match, we would want to identify those as likely duplicates.

So the output might look something like this:

[image]

I would like to also be able to adjust the number of columns based on the number of NAs (e.g. - in the last example for "Daniel Brown" consider a match of 2 columns a likely duplicate if the City and State are NA) but that is more of a nice to have at this point.

I believe I could get an answer by identifying duplicates based on the name plus one other column (e.g. - find all duplicates for FirstName, LastName, and City.  Then FirstName, LastName, and State. etc...), and then using Reduce or something similar to merge the data and then try to count how many duplicates for each group of duplicate names resulted.
However, that seems very manual,  difficult to adjust/scale, and there feels like there should be a way of testing if X number of columns are duplicated for each naming pair (one that is more direct and readable).

Thoughts?

---

2023-05-18 - including the final/altered solution, in case in helps anyone else (see below using the original dummy data above).
Changes made:

- Used mutate instead of summarise because I wanted to keep each original row
- identified specific columns (original data has many and could change)
- copied the original columns to keep the original data at the end.
- added a weight per column because a duplicate in one column may be more indicative of a duplicate row than a duplicate in another column
- added both the sum of duplicate columns and an index figure (weighted sum so the higher the index, the higher the likelihood that the row is a duplicate)

```
# Identify Columns and weights to check for suspected Duplicates
  Check_Col_Names <- c("City" ,"State", "Group1", "Group2", "Group3")
  Check_Col_Weights <- c(3,2,3,1,1)

# Copy & Add "Du" columns to use for comparison
  df <- cbind(df, 
              rename_with(df[,Check_Col_Names], 
              .fn = ~paste0("Du_", .), 
              .cols = Check_Col_Names)
              )

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(FirstName, LastName) %>% # group data by the same name
  mutate(  # changing selected columns within each group
    across(
      .cols = starts_with("Du_"),  # calculate across selected columns...
      .fns = ~ length(unique(.x)) == 1  # ...that we have the same value in that column
    )
  ) |>
  ungroup() |> # Ungrouping by names
  rowwise() |>  # re-grouping by rows
  # Count number of matching columns
  mutate(
    Dupl_QtyCols = sum(c_across(cols = starts_with("Du_")))  
  ) |>
  # Create weighted sum as index for likelihood of duplicate entry
  mutate(
    Dupl_CheckIndex = (across(.cols = starts_with("Du_")) %>% as.matrix()) %*% Check_Col_Weights  
  ) |>
  ungroup()

df <- df |> select(-starts_with("Du_")) # Remove temp fields
df
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I hope this helps and Thank you to Su Na for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, try code below. I write some explanation saying what I do per line.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(FirstName, LastName) %>% # group data by the same name
  summarise(  # summarise info within each group
    across(
      .cols = dplyr::everything(),  # calculate across all columns...
      .fns = ~ length(unique(.x)) == 1  # ...that we have the same value in that column
    ),
    .groups = "drop"  # drop the grouping after this
  ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%  # re-grouping by rows
  mutate(
    sum_like = sum(c_across(cols = -c(FirstName, LastName)))  # calculate the sum-ups across all columns
  )
```

Resulting data frame goes like this, the `sum_like` column is the "likelyhood" you need.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
# Rowwise: 
  FirstName LastName City  State Group1 Group2 Group3 sum_like
  <chr>     <chr>    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>     <int>
1 Daniel    Adams    FALSE FALSE TRUE   TRUE   TRUE          3
2 Daniel    Andrews  TRUE  FALSE TRUE   TRUE   TRUE          4
3 Daniel    Brown    FALSE FALSE TRUE   TRUE   TRUE          3
4 Daniel    Thomas   FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE          1
5 Daniel    White    FALSE TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE          4
```

If you want to, you can learn all these `tidyverse` data manipulation tricks from [R for Data Science chapter 5](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html).

Comment: Thanks - I presume that if I wanted to keep each row (as these aren't definite), I could switch it to mutate instead of summarize and add an additional ungroup before the sum_like creation.  Also, if wanting to keep the original column data (prior to them being changed to T/F), the best way would be to identify and then duplicate the columns to use ahead of time.